# Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$. Show that $Y = \mathrm{e}^{-X/\theta} \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1]$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$. Show that $Y = \mathrm{e}^{-X/\theta} \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1]$.

Hi, I tried to prove this in my tutorial but I got stuck trying to prove it using MGF. Can someone help me with the first method? I was planning to get the $My(t)$ expression to see if I can see any similarity with that of a uniform distribution. Is my train of thoughts correct?

I also tried to prove using the pdf of $Y$. I have written my questions in red, and I was wondering how to prove the part where the uniform distribution is valid from $0$ (exclusive) to $1$ inclusive.

Attached are my workings, I hope someone can enlighten me on this! thank you!

EDIT:
**I have taken down my detailed workings as I have verified that the workings are correct.*

To answer my above questions, The  $My(t)$ expression can be gotten via a direct integration from E($\mathrm{e}^{tY}$) , and then a comparison of that with the  $Mx(t)$ of a uniform distribution.

Also, the Uniform distribution is valid (0,1] because the exp distribution is valid from x more than or equals to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construing $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\theta)$ to mean the distribution of $X$ is
$$
e^{-x/\theta} \, \dfrac{dx} \theta \text{ for } x\ge 0,
$$
I'd start by showing that
$$
\Pr(X>x) = e^{-x/\theta} \text{ for } x\ge 0.
$$
Then
$$
\Pr(e^{-X/\theta} \le y)  = \Pr\left( X \ge -\theta\log y \right) = e^{-(-\theta\log y)/\theta} = y, \text{ for } 0 \le y\le 1. 
$$

Comment: michael what is meant by $e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}dx/\theta$

Comment: @Upstart : $\dfrac{dx}\theta$ is the measure that assigns measure $\displaystyle \int_a^b \frac {dx} \theta = \frac{b-a} \theta $ to each interval $[a,b].$ Thus $\displaystyle e^{-x/\theta} \frac{dx} \theta$ assigns measure $\displaystyle \int_a^b e^{-x/\theta}\, \frac{dx} \theta$ to the interval $[a,b].$ Restricted to the interval $[0,\infty),$ this is a probability distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: kk thanx for the explaination

Answer (score 0):

You have exponential distribution and you are transforming it into another r.v. by running it through its of *cdf*, well, one minus its own *cdf*. That the new r.v. is uniform is then a consequence of [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). The proof in the link uses standard *cdf* method for deriving distribution of a [function of random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables).

Answer (score 0):

$$P(e^{-X/\theta}\le y)=P(\frac{-X}\theta\le \log y)=P(-X\le -\theta\log y)$$
$$ = P(X\ge -\theta\log y)=\int_{-\theta \log y}^\infty \theta e^{-\theta x}\, dx,\qquad 0\le y \le 1.$$

$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\theta \log y}^\infty \theta e^{-\theta\cdot x}dx.$$

If you differentiate with the Leibnitz rule you get

$$f_Y(y)=\theta^2 y^{\theta^2-1} \text{ with } 0\le y \le 1$$

And this pdf is certainly not of a Uniform Distribution.
If you are considering the pdf as $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$. Then you will get the pdf of a uniform distribution.

Comment: I believe that the problem is the distribution, I mean, the distribution of a exponential X with mean $\theta$ is $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$...In this way you find that $P(Y\leq t)=t$

Comment: You confuse things when you use the same letter, $y$, to refer to two different things.  You need $$\int_{-\theta\log y}^\infty f(x)\,dx$$ where $f$ is the density, and the letters $x$ and $y$ are different: $x$ goes from $-\theta\log y$ to $\infty.$ The other problem is that sometimes people write "exponentially distributed with parameter $\theta$" when they mean the expected value is $\theta$, and sometimes they write the same thing when they mean the expected value is $1/\theta.$ In this case, we need the latter interpretation. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the distinction between $\geq$ and $>$ is not important, because the exponential distribution is absolutely continuous and every point has zero probability mass.   That is: $~\mathsf P(X=-\theta\ln y)~=~0$

So...

$\begin{align}F_Y(y) &= \mathsf P(Y\leqslant y)
\\ &= \mathsf P(e^{-X/\theta}\leqslant y)
\\ &= \mathsf P(-X/\theta \leqslant \ln y)
\\ &= \mathsf P(X\geqslant -\theta\ln y) 
\\ &= \big(1-F_X(-\theta\ln y\;^-)\big)\cdot\mathbf 1_{(-\theta\ln y)~\in[0;\infty)}~+\mathbf 1_{(-\theta\ln y)~\in(-\infty;0)}
\\ &= e^{-(-\theta\ln y)/\theta}\cdot\mathbf 1_{\ln y~\in(-\infty;0]}~+\mathbf 1_{\ln y~\in(0;\infty)}
\\ &= y \cdot\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1]}~+\mathbf 1_{y~\in(1;\infty)}
\end{align}$

Which is the CDF of a Uniform(0;1] distribution.

---

PS: The indicator function's interval comes because $F_X((-\theta\ln y)\,^-)$ is supported when $(-\theta\ln y)\in[0;\infty)$.   Then rearrange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The question asked to prove that Y is a uniform distribution (0,1] . I still do not know how to show that it includes 1, cause as shown in my working, I only managed to show till (0,1) .

Comment: The intervals differ by a null measured point and have identical distributions.  I may not have been as rigorous as I could with the bounds.  I will revise.

Comment: oh okay, Thank you! :)